# Birds nesting in my truck grill near radiator

Tags: engine

Bird are nesting in the front grill of my 2018 GMC Sierra.

I am afraid it will cause a fire and this area is very hard to get to.

Any ideas on how can i stop them from building  nests in my grill ?

Comment: Place a plastic owl in front of the truck

Comment: Obtain an outdoor cat?

Comment: real looking rubber snake will run them off.

Comment: Do you drive this vehicle daily?

Comment: Fill all the gaps with expanding foam. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Move the truck; ( also a GMC Sierra, but I doubt birds have a brand preference ) If you can't get it into a garage, maybe back into the space, maybe throw something like a tarp over the grill. I have watched Carolina wrens ( which you may not have) build a nest in my grill in a couple hours. I was visiting so I just drove away. Some birds can be persistent, it took three days of disruptions for me to stop a kingfisher from building a nest.